# Issue with uploading ci project on server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am receiving the below error when I am uploading my CI3 project on to the server:

> ini_set(): Headers already sent. You cannot change the session
>   module's ini settings at this timeFilename: Session/Session.php
>
> Line Number: 375
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /home/adityanamansingh/rkvd1.adityanamansingh.com/application/controllers/Home.php
>   Line: 9 Function: library
>
> File: /home/adityanamansingh/rkvd1.adityanamansingh.com/index.php
>   Line: 315 Function: require_once

What should be the way to remove such error from my project?
I am not receiving the same error on my localhost.

Comment: Try to remove the closing tag of the controller, if exists.

Comment: Also remove whitespaces at the beginning of your php files( controllers, models, libs,..etc)

Comment: It is not there.

Comment: But, I have not experienced this issue before.

Comment: Sometimes, it happens :)

Comment: Sir, If I remove the session library from myy controller, then it is working properly.

Comment: have you added the session library to your autoload file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)